# Collecting form values and displaying in a textarea with PHP

Tags: php, forms

I'm not new to HTML/CSS, but I definitely am with PHP, and haven't been able to figure out how to collect form values and display them in a textarea. I've researched at least 30 sites and have found pieces of code here and there that will do what I want. I just don't know how to put it all together and make it work.

- I have found how to collect input values
- I have found how to create an array to collect checkbox values
- I have found how to collect textarea values
- I have found how to display collected values in a textarea
- I haven't found how to get all of this to work together :(

The requirements for this personal project is as follows:

Collect customer name, domain or customer number, phone number input values, any checked values, any values in the customer issue, customer needs, and purchase/renewal textareas, and then displaying all of it in the notes textarea. Each value displayed should have a space, a dash, and another space " - " concatenated to the end of all values except the last value, which should end in a period.

The capture button should collect all the values and send to PHP processing to display in the notes textarea. The copy button (obviously) will copy the values in the notes textarea and display a 1 to 2 second message stating "notes were copied". The clear button (again, obviously) clears the form. I will be the only user so validation is not required.

I don't expect anyone to do all the work for me, but I'm really struggling and tips, pointers, and quality reference websites will be much appreciated.

The website code I've put together is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.png">

        <title>One Pass Call</title>

        <link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./includes/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./includes/themes/default/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="./includes/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="./includes/js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top visible-xs">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">ONE PASS <span class="strap">CALL</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="selected">
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#customer-experience"><i class="icon-phone icon-1x"></i> Customer Experience</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#consultation"><i class="icon-comments icon-1x"></i> Consultation</a>
                        </li>           
                        <li>
                            <a href="#consultation-details"><i class="icon-puzzle-piece icon-1x"></i> Consultation Details</a>
                        </li>           
                        <li>
                            <a href="#offer-and-close"><i class="icon-credit-card icon-1x"></i> Offer and Close</a>
                        </li>           
                        <li>
                            <a href="#notes"><i class="icon-keyboard icon-1x"></i> Notes</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="sidemenu" class="sidemenu hidden-xs">
            <li>
                <a class="sidemenu-brand" href="#">ONE PASS CALL</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="selected" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home icon-2x"></i> <br/>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#customer-experience"><i class="fa fa-phone icon-2x"></i> <br/>Customer Experience</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#consultation"><i class="fa fa-comments icon-2x"></i> <br/>Consultation</a>
            </li>           
            <li>
                <a href="#consultation-details"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece icon-2x"></i> <br/>Consultation Details</a>
            </li>           
            <li>
                <a href="#offer-and-close"><i class="fa fa-credit-card icon-2x"></i> <br/>Offer and Close</a>
            </li>           
            <li>
                <a href="#notes"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o icon-2x"></i> <br/>Notes</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="content-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <img src="./includes/img/gd-header-reg.jpg" class="pull-right img-responsive"  alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h1 class="text-center">
                A Recipe for Success on Every Call!
            </h1>
            <hr/>

            <div id="features">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row feature">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a name="customer-experience"></a>
                        <h1 class="gd-orange">Customer Experience</h1>
                        <br />
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="customer.php" novalidate autocomplete="off">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent properly greet the customer and confirm the call back number?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Sales and Support, this is (your name). Who am I speaking with today?</p>
                                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label" for="name"><strong>Customer's Name:</strong></label>
                                                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Customer&#039;s name..." />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Hi (customer's name), do you have your domain or customer number available to verify?</p>
                                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">  
                                                    <label class="control-label" for="account"><strong>Domain or Customer Number:</strong></label>
                                                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> </span>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account" name="account" value="" placeholder="Domain/Account#..." />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Thank you, and is this a good number to call you at if we get disconnected?</p>
                                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                                    <label for="phone" class="control-label"><strong>Phone Number:</strong></label>
                                                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> </span>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone number..." />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent build rapport and deliver a good experience for the customer?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>How is your day going so far?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Great! Can you briefly let me know how I can help you today?</p>
                                            </li>                                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent actively listen to the customer and clarify their concern?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Ok, can you be a little more specific for me?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>So to restate what I'm hearing... does that sound right?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Well ok, let's get you all fixed up!</p>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="control-label"><strong>Customer's Issue:</strong></label></div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue1" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="GD Password Reset" >
                                                                <label for="issue1">GD Password Reset</label>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue2" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="WSE Password Reset" >
                                                                <label for="issue2">WSE Password Reset</label>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue3" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="O365 Password Reset" >
                                                                <label for="issue3">O365 Password Reset</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue4" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="Android Setup" >
                                                                <label for="issue4">Android Setup</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue5" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="iPhone/iPad Setup" >
                                                                <label for="issue5">iPhone/iPad Setup</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue6" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="Outlook Setup" >
                                                                <label for="issue6">Outlook Setup</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue7" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="Apple/Mac Mail Setup" >
                                                                <label for="issue7">Apple/Mac Mail Setup</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue8" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="Alias Setup" >
                                                                <label for="issue8">Alias Setup</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue9" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="Forwarding Setup" >
                                                                <label for="issue9">Forwarding Setup</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue10" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="Migration Issue" >
                                                                <label for="issue10">Migration Issue</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue11" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="Known Issue" >
                                                                <label for="issue11">Known Issue</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                                <input id="issue12" name="checkIssue[]" type="checkbox" value="Out of Scope" >
                                                                <label for="issue12">Out of Scope</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>                                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="details"></label>
                                        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> </span>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="details" name="details" rows="5"  placeholder="Customer&#039;s issue..." /></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent set proper expectations? 
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>First off I want to set some expectations as to what I'll be doing for you, ok?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>I'm going to be working with you to take care of the problem.</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>I'll ask you questions along the way to determine how to best resolve the problem.</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>If possible, please keep answers simple so we're not stuck working on this for a long time.</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>The large page titles and bolded headings work fine if I need to ask what page you are looking at, ok?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Now, if the issue falls outside our scope of support I'll do what I can to point you in the right direction, ok?</p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />
                                <a name="consultation"></a>
                                <h1 class="gd-orange">Consultation</h1>
                                <br />                                                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent engage the customer in a needs based conversation which led to a personalized recommendation?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>First I want to know your comfort level with computers. Are you a neophyte, semi-confident, pretty confident or a seasoned pro when it comes to computers?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Ok (customer name), as I run tests and troubleshoot I'll review the account to make sure everything is in good standing.</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>While I'm doing that can I ask some questions about your business to see if we have other services that can help grow your business?</p>
                                            </li>                                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />
                                <a name="consultation-details"></a>
                                <h1 class="gd-orange">Consultation Details</h1>
                                <br />                                                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent ask questions to uncover or understand the customer's need?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>                                            
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Since we're on the subject of email, is there anything about your email service that isn't meeting your needs? Ok, please tell me more...</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Tell me about your website. Is there anything it isn't doing for you that you wish it was?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Do you ever wonder why you don't get better search rankings or more traffic to your website?</p>
                                            </li>                                           
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>How happy are you with your current website hosting service? Are you unhappy enough with it to consider bringing your website to GoDaddy?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>How would you feel about having all your internet services in one account, with one company, instead having things spread amongst several companies?</p>                                             
                                            </li>                                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="needs"><strong>Customer Needs:</strong></label>
                                        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> </span>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="needs"  name="needs" rows="5" col="1"  placeholder="Customer needs..." /></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent make a personalized recommendation based on the customer's unique journey?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Well (customer's name), based on what you've told me I'd have to say that (product/s) will be a perfect solution for you.</p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent miss any opportunities on the call?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>One thing I noticed is you don't have your website secured... has anyone here ever pointed this out to you?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Your billing dates for your products are scattered all over. Would having everything on the same billing cycle be convenient for you?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Would you like me to delete the expired credit cards on the account?</p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />
                                <a name="offer-and-close"></a>
                                <h1 class="gd-orange">Offer and Close</h1>
                                <br />                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent close the sale based on the recommendation?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Ok, sounds like we have the perfect package put together for you.</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Would you like to go with the 5 year option for the best discounts? Or would you prefer to go with a 3 year option.</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Great, let's go ahead and get you checked out. Would you like to use the credit card ending in (xxxx), or a different credit card?</p>                                               
                                            </li>                                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="transaction"><strong>Purchase/Renewal:</strong></label>
                                        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> </span>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="transaction" name="transaction" rows="5" col="1"  placeholder="Customer purchased/renewed... " /></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent attempt to overcome objections?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Ok, I can see where you're coming from. So far we've agreed the (product/s) we talked about will definitely benefit you.</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Is there anything I didn't explain properly which is keeping you from moving forward? Or maybe you have more questions?</p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>I understand you're not the decision maker for the account. Can I send you an email so you can follow up with me once you speak with your manager?</p>
                                            </li>                                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br />
                                <hr class="visible-lg" />
                                <br />                              
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <h2>
                                            Did the agent offer to set up the products and provide next steps?
                                        </h2>
                                        <br />
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>                                        
                                                <p>Once we finish with the purchase I'll help you set everything up and make sure everything is running smoothly.</p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <footer>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <a name="notes"></a>
                            <h1 class="gd-orange">Notes</h1>
                            <h3 class="justify" style="text-align: center">Copy and paste your notes.</h3>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="notes"></label>
                                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> </span>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes" rows="18"  placeholder="These are your notes..." ></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group submit col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="notes" style="display: block;">Submit Button</label>
                                    <div class="progress" style="display: none; z-index: -1; position: absolute;">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width:100%"></div> 
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-footer" name="capture" value="">Capture</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-footer" name="copy" value="">Copy</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-footer" name="clear" value="">Clear</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container jf-thankyou" style="display:none;" data-redirect="" data-seconds="1">
                        <h3>Your notes have been copied!</h3>
                    </div>          
                </div>
            </footer>
            <div id="footer-bottom">
                &copy; 2016 Johnny Marrero. All rights reserved.
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="./includes/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./includes/js/jquery.event.move.js"></script>
        <script src="./includes/js/jquery.event.swipe.js"></script>
        <script src="./includes/js/default.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would it be easier to achieve the desired outcome using JavaScript instead of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand request and response process in http server and form submit process in html. follow the below step.

1.First put all your form fields like input, text area, checkbox inside form tag in html html/php file like below

```
<form **action="welcome.php"** method="get">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input **type="submit"** value="Submit">
</form>
```

2. As you can see in the form tag the action (bold) attribute contains .php file name. And a submit type input button is inside the form.
3. when you will click on the submit button on the html page the form will submitted into the php file mentioned in the action attribute and you can get the form input values in the that php(welcome.php) file
4. make sure its running under a http server like xampp, wamp, apache etc or else the http request and response will not work.
5. once you receive data in the php file you can display it, save into database or can send it to other pages.

a typical php file which receive data from html forms looks like below.

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]." ".$_POST["lname"]; ?><br>


</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp -link to get more basic details

Comment: Thank you, Aniruddha. Unfortunately I have already visited the link you provided. I understand the basic concepts of 'designing' the form. If you examine the code you'll see the form is already put together correctly, as you suggested. My problem is getting the functions, for loops, array, and displaying the values in the notes textarea. I've tried all the examples I've found and they work, but when I add it all up together I can't get the PHP script to work at all. So in a nutshell, it's getting the processing to work that I'm having a problem with.